# Why can't I use UIProgressViewStyle.bar in tvOS?

Tags: uikit, tvos, uiprogressview

I'm writing a tvOS app using Xcode 9.2, targeting tvOS 11.

I have a UIProgressView and I'm trying to set it's style to `.bar` but Xcode says ".bar is not available".

How can I use the `.bar` style for the UIProgressView on my tvOS app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The style `bar` of UIProgressView is only defined in the iOS SDK. It is defined as __TVOS_PROHIBITED in UIKit:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIProgressViewStyle) {
    UIProgressViewStyleDefault,     // normal progress bar
    UIProgressViewStyleBar __TVOS_PROHIBITED,     // for use in a toolbar
};
```

Also described like that in the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprogressviewstyle/1619835-bar

[image: Bar Style Documentation]

Comment: Ended up using https://github.com/gregttn/GTProgressBar instead.  CocoaPods spec didn't include tvOS but I submitted a PR to fix that.  Works great.